# Setting a cookie with samesite none on Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, cookies, samesite

I am trying to set a specific cookie to have samesite='None' for a Django project on version `2.2.x`. I continue to get the below error.

```py
raise ValueError('samesite must be "lax" or "strict".')
```

which I can see is coming from `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/response.py`

```py
if samesite:
  if samesite.lower() not in ('lax', 'strict'):
    raise ValueError('samesite must be "lax" or "strict".')
  self.cookies[key]['samesite'] = samesite
```

I have tried to following:

1. Set this globally in settings eg `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`, `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`
2. Setting this on the cookie that need it via `set_cookie(name, value=value, secure=True, samesite='None')`

Both approaches don't work. I have also tried to installed the package [`django-cookies-samesite`](https://pypi.org/project/django-cookies-samesite/) and adding its middleware, however it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```py
# example
MIDDLEWARE = (
    "django_cookies_samesite.middleware.CookiesSameSite",
    # other middleware
)
```

When I set the value to `None` instead of `'None'` no value is added and I believe Chrome falls back to `lax` when there isn't a value there.

I have also tried setting a cookie outside of the Django `set_cookie` without any luck:

```py
# this fails with AttributeError: 'JsonResponse' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'
response["Set-Cookie"] = f"{name}={value}; Secure={False}; SameSite='None'; Path=/"
```

```py
# this adds the cookie however doesn't parse it correctly so it fails
response.cookies[name] = f"{name}={value}; Secure={False}; SameSite='None'; Path=/"

# eg
Set-Cookie: my_name="my_value Secure=False\073 SameSite='None'\073 Path=/"
# where the other cookies look like
Set-Cookie: my_name=my_value; expires=Wed, 28 Apr 2021 02:51:02 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/
```

Is there a way around this? I can see the newer versions of Django support this however trying to see if there is a way to solve with the our current version of Django (`2.2`).